# Issue importing CSV with CSVT (fields format not applied - QGIS 3.18)

Tags: qgis, csv, field-mapping

I'm trying to import a CSV file with some data and hoping that QGIS will properly format the fields type but so far no luck.
I have my data in a file called `coords.csv` and I made a single line text file for fields format called `coords.csvt` (both files located in same folder)

My CSV is like this:

```
picnum,east,south,stamp
1,145.214879,-15.473314,06/05/2021 3:53:12 PM
2,145.214854,-15.473339,06/05/2021 3:53:13 PM
3,145.214822,-15.473369,06/05/2021 3:53:14 PM
4,145.214786,-15.473408,06/05/2021 3:53:15 PM
```

My CSVT is like that:

```
"Integer","String(12)","String(12)","String(50)"
```

To import: *Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer* ;
I then select my CSV file, set the coordinates and CRS, and then add the layer.

But when checking fields format, I get:

[image: screenshot1]

When I am expecting to see this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I tried using small caps for the CSVT file but no luck either. I'm using QGIS 3.18.2 on Windows 10

Comment: can you try text to column in your .csv sheet to extract these coordinates, such as 145.214879,-15.473314, to separated column, then import into QGIS?

Comment: How would I do that? Apologies but I'm new to QGIS

Comment: Your csvt is wrong. string  is for alfanumeric fields. So it must be like this "Integer","real","real","string". Here https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/ yo can find more information. there is also a way to speciffy the date and time

Comment: If I use `"Integer","Real","Real","String(50)"` on my csvt file, I still get the _stamp_ field as *text* and not *string 50* as expected

Comment: So far as I'm aware, string type and text type are synonymous in QGIS. Have I missed something?

Comment: I'm trying to get fields with fixed width (no luck so far), so maybe Text has no set width (or maybe 254) while String has a set value?